# Whats wrong with this RewriteRule for .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewrite my url:

```
localhost/users/045da557b7
```

to

```
localhost/users/index.html?userID=045da557b7
```

here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-z]{10})/$ /index.html?userID=$1 [L]
```

But the browser gives me 404 back.

I have the rewrite mod uncommented in the httpd.conf.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Obvious question, but is the `.htaccess` located in `/users/`?

Comment: With RegEx, do the delimiters not need to be the first and last character? e.g. `/^([0-9a-z]{10})$/`

also, the section you're trying to match wouldn't be the start of the string being passed so not sure if the `^` is correct.

Maybe `/(?<=[\/])([0-9a-z]{10})$/` would be better. (Not sure if you can use look-behind feature here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper `RewriteBase` by placing this rule in `/users/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /users/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.html?userID=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: that worked very well. I also had to enable AllowOverride All ;) thanks

Comment: just one more Question. Can I read the GET params still with javascript with this method? It seems not to work.

Comment: This is an internal server side rewrite so JS won't know of this GET param being added. For JS to know you will have to do extarnal redirect using `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ index.html?userID=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]`

Comment: Ah now it works. But the beautiful address is now messed up again :D I do not work with PHP, instead node.js. but I use apache for html and node for ajax stuff. So I do not have dynamic serverside pages. Maybe I am doing everything wrong. Any idea to improve this?

Comment: That's the thing for JS to know about new GET params we need to use `R` flag but that will change your pretty URL. I don't think you can  avoid it. May be loading this URL via AJAX is the way but I am not a front end web developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
^/([0-9a-z]){10}/$
a                b
   cccccccc dddd

a - anchor pattern to start of string
b - anchor pattern to end of string
c - allow numbers and lower case alphabet
d - must have exactly 10 characters


users/045da557b7

16 characters  (past your limit of 10)
contains a / - not in your list of allowed characters
```

You've basically said "allow at most 10 charccters of 0-9a-z", then passed in 17 characters and include characters that aren't allowed. So your entire pattern will refuse to match.